# What is a "cue" in the XACT API?

Tags: xna

I understand that a wave bank is a collection of .wav data files and that a sound bank is a collection of tracks, each having a .wav with properties. But what is a cue?

Answer (score 4):

A [cue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.audio.cue.aspx) is a like a trigger used to invoke a sound. A cue has multiple sounds associated with it that all play back once the cue is activated.